# Opening two ports using webSockets on the same HTML page (one page getting loaded through iframe)

Tags: html, iframe, websocket

Is it possible to open two ports on one HTML page? 
I am using webSockets.

Actually, there is this page1 having port 8000.
page1 is using iframe to load page2 having port 7999.

Now when i am loading Page1 on server, connection is not getting established for page2 (that is Port: 7999).

Please help !

Comment: To answer this more information is required.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to use a different IP and port for an iframe. But I'm a bit confused. You have your web page, which is URL 1, than you have an iframe within your web page, which URL 2, and than you have a WebSocket, which would be URL 3. Which URL is the different one: from the iframe or from the WebSocket?

Comment: @Kris I am using WebSocket to connect these url1 and url2 with the server. <br/>
Url1 is loading the Url2 (as an iframe).
But the connection with Url2 is getting failed.

In Url1.js i am listening to the port 8000
and in url2.js i am listening to port 7999

But, connection to port 7999 is getting failed.